# how to get the list of order which i am entering into input box

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a module of billing where i need to create new div on enter click on quantity. Data show in list. I am inserting these values
Example:-

```
item-id       item-name  quantity    unit      price      Amount 
1.            001        rice        5         20         100
2.            002        dal         2         15         30
```

I want to show these value. But my code is running one time. This is my AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#itemid1').keyup(function () {
        var v = document.getElementById("itemid1").value;
        var v1 = document.getElementById("qty").value;
        var data = 'itemid=' + v + '&qty=' + v1;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'B_billing',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (json) {
                $('#id1').val(json.itemid);
                $('#iname1').text(json.itemname);
                $('#qty1').val(json.qty);
                $('#pr1').text(json.price);
                $('#amount').text(json.amt);
            }
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qty').keyup(function () {
        var v = document.getElementById("itemid1").value;
        var v1 = document.getElementById("qty").value;
        var data = 'itemid=' + v + '&qty=' + v1;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'B_billing1',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (json) {
                $('#amount').text(json.amt);
            }
        });
    });
});

function runScript(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        p = $('#qty').val();
        console.log(p);

        p1 = $('#itemid1').val();
        console.log(p1);

        var n = '';
        var txt = $('#iname1').html();
        $('#iname2').html(txt);
        $('#iname1').html(n);

        var txt1 = $('#pr1').html();
        $('#pr2').html(txt1);
        $('#pr1').html(n);

        var txt2 = $('#amount').html();
        $('#amount2').html(txt2);
        $('#amount').html(n);

        document.getElementById('qty2').innerHTML = p;
        document.getElementById('qty').value = "";
        document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML = p1;
        document.getElementById('itemid1').value = "";
    }
}
```

Please give me some advice on how to add list of billing item.

Comment: yes your code will work only for one time plz check in success block. here there is no loop.

Comment: can you please help me where should i have to put loop ?

Comment: first paste your complete code here means putting data to json obj.

Comment: means i have to also show you my html or servlet code ?

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
               json.put("itemid", itemid);
               json.put("qty", qty);
               json.put("amt", amount);
               out.print(json);

Comment: can you please give me your email id i'll mail u?